# Rebuild Haml assets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm working on an angular project and I'm using the `angular-rails-templates` gem to manage the templates. I have a custom method in rails in order to create 'partials' between my templates.

```
module HamlHelper
  def include_partial(partial, locals = {})
    Haml::Engine.new(File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/assets/javascripts/#{partial}")).render(Object.new, locals)
  end
end
```

So that I can have in my haml templates for example:

`/assets/javascripts/templates/page1.html.haml`

```
- header =  { title: 'Page 1'}
.page
  = include_partial 'shared/header.html.haml', locals: header
  ...
```

and

`/assets/javascripts/shared/header.html.haml`

```
%header.header
  .header__container
    %h1.header__title= locals[:title]
    ...
```

The problem I'm having is that if I want to modify the header.html.haml partial, the changes are only updated when I modify the page1.html.haml file which contains the partial. So since page1 is not modified, Rails thinks that it wasn't modified and then page1 is not processed again. Is there a solution for this?

NOTE: I used here a very basic example for my partial, but in reality is a more complex one. So using `ng-include` of angular is not what I need.